# How to extract keywords from a body of text in PHP

Tags: php, taxonomy

Currently I'm leveraging http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html which isn't ideal for performance and quality reasons. Before I embark on spending time on writing a system I wanted to see if there are any other available options that can do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A quick web search for: Yahoo "term extraction" alternatives

Turns up: http://fivefilters.org/term-extraction/
as the first result.  It looks decent and has pointers to others at the bottom.

Comment: Though I'd prefer something in PHP

Comment: So I unmarked this as the answer because this solution is AGPL and unfortunately I'm not willing to open source my web application (though I am a open source developer).

Comment: It uses Topia as its base which is not GPL'ed.  It is under the ZPL.  See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/topia.termextract/

Comment: Thanks Rasmus. Just wanted to point out that we've now ported Topia's Term Extractor to PHP: http://code.fivefilters.org/term-extraction

And for anyone looking to switch over from Yahoo's Term Extractor without too much rewriting, we have a web service layer (for self hosting) on top of this code. It offers a Yahoo compatibility mode (same request parameters and response format), so switching could be as simple as changing the base URL. http://fivefilters.org/term-extraction/

Full disclosure: I'm a developer on this project.

Answer (score 1):

Used this few times, enough good:
http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/php_tip_how_extract_keywords_web_page